# MySQL .NET connector causing many exceptions when using load balancing

Tags: c#, mysql

We have an ASP.NET project, made in .NET Framework 4.6, that uses the MySQL.Data nuget package, version 8.0.29. We have multiple MySQL databases in a cluster. The MySQL connector has functionality for adding multiple hostnames (comma separated) so that the traffic will be split between multiple databases. We tried using this and it seems to work fine on our test environment, but on production we are seeing many exceptions in the Event Viewer of the Windows Server. Production has, of course, much more traffic than the test environment, so that might be part of the cause.

These exceptions do not occur when we only use one of the database. We have tried all of them seperately and they all work without problem on production by themselves, just not together.

This is an example of our connection string:

```
server=example1.com,example2.com,example3.com;port=25060;uid=username;pwd=password;database=database;pooling=false;Allow User Variables=True;CharSet=utf8
```

(Pooling is set to false, because pooling is causing other problems for us which is a separate issue.)

Here are the errors we are getting:

```
Exception type: MySqlException
    Exception message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.<>c.<Open>b__40_0(Exception ex)
   at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException
    Exception message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.get_ConnectionString()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

```
Exception type: SocketException
    Exception message: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySqlConnection connection, String originalConnectionString, String& connectionString, Boolean mySqlPoolManager)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? Is it something we're doing wrong?

Comment: In test environment also you have multiple database servers?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, I even copied the connection string from production and used that on test and it still worked on test. The test and production run on the same server (Wndows Server 2019 standard with IIS).

Comment: This appears to be a known bug in MySql.Data: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100327. You might want to try https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector as an alternative. (Disclaimer: I'm the lead author.) If you're using .NET 4.6.1 (or later) you can use v2.2.5; if you're using .NET 4.6 then the latest version you can use is 2.1.13.